# ALT+F4 logs me off immediatly in remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I am using a remote desktop connection to a Windows Server 2016 Std. My Client is working on a windows 10.

If I press Alt+F4 at the desktop in Fullscreen all of my remote programs are closing and the system is logging me of from the TerminalServer.

I thought that there would be a dialog which asks me what I want to do (log off, shutdown, restart etc.)

Maybe this is a problem with my permissions on the Server?

Comment: Doesn’t sound like it.  What documentation have you read indicates this behavior isn’t supposed to happen?

Comment: @Ramhound: if a user with administrative privileges does the same he gets the dialogue.
Even in my local win-10, if I press ALT+F4 I get the question what kind of action I want to perform-.

Comment: Check "local ressources" tab

Comment: @davidbaumann I checked the local ressources. 
The Problem isnt that the shortcuts are not working. The Problem is that this shortcut is not working right (in my opinion)

Comment: I gues it's set to "execute locally", so you close the RDP window.

Comment: @davidbaumann if I close my RDP window the session should be only disconnected. But in my case I am logged off

Comment: See this description (and workaround):
https://serverfault.com/questions/967452/windows-server-2019-altf4-logs-off-immediately-without-prompt-dialog